# What will be the angle that this straight line makes with the positive side of the x-axis?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification

*This question came in the Bangladesh Agricultural University admission exam 2018-19*

Q) A perpendicular line $OC$ is drawn from the origin on $x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha=p$. What is the value of the angle formed by this line with the positive side of the x-axis?

(a) $\alpha$

(b) $\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$

(c) $\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha$

(d) $\pi + \alpha$

**My attempt:**

$$x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha=p$$

$$y\cos\alpha=-x\sin\alpha+p$$

$$y=-x\tan\alpha + \frac{p}{\cos\alpha}$$

$$y=x\tan(\pi-\alpha)+\frac{p}{\cos\alpha}$$

So, the angle that the given straight line seems to be making with the positive side of the x-axis is $\pi-\alpha$. I don't see this angle listed among the options. The third-party question bank says that the answer is (b). I don't understand how the answer could be (b). Which should be the correct answer?

---

A picture for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\angle COA=\alpha$$

and triangle $OAC$ is right triangle,

So the angle $\angle CAO=\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$,

$$\Rightarrow  \angle MAX=\pi-\angle CAO=\frac{\pi}2+\alpha$$

Comment: There has been a misunderstanding. We have to find the angle that the straight line ML makes with the positive side of the x-axis. In other words, we have to find $\angle CAX$ Also, $\angle COA=\alpha$.

Comment: Ok, edited already.